# SlickGrid not displayed

Tags: asp.net, slickgrid

Newbie here..Currently developing my 1st ASP.NET web application. I am trying to use SlickGrid. Somehow the grid doesnt appear at all, even the header is not displayed :-(

**Below are my Index.cshtml code :**

```
@model IEnumerable<E_2.Models.DYE>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/slick.grid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/slick.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/slick.grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SlickGridTest.js")" type="text/javascript">

</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="teamGrid" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**..this is my SlickGridTest.js script**

```
var grid;
var columns = [
    { id: "ID", name: "ID", field: "ID" },
    { id: "DESCRIPTION", name: "DESCRIPTION", field: "DESCRIPTION" },
];

var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
};

$(function () {
    var myData = [];
    $.getJSON('/DYE/ReloadDyeData', function (data) {
        myData = data;
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", myData, columns, options);
    });
```

**..my model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace E_2.Models
{
    public partial class DYE
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string COLOR_CODE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> VALID_UNTIL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**..and the controller part that reload the data **

```
public string ReloadDyeData()
{
    var dyes = db.DYEs.ToList();
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(dyes);
}
```

because of lack experience in this HTML, JavaScriot and ASP.NET , I really have no idea where will be the root problems.

Comment: note : i have run the debugging using Firebug and found that = jquery.event.drag-2.2.min.js, slick.core.js and slick.grid.js is called. But somehow "SlickGridTest.js" is not being called (not shown in script debug selection).and some edit has been done into "SlickGridTest.js". but I don't know why it is not being called

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be occuring because you're loading the .js file in the wrong place.

At the bottom of your view (after your last cshtml code) you need to add a section for your scripts, like this

```
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/yourfile"></script>
}
```

this is a fast answer, could easily be something else

Comment: the reference section has been added (all 5 lines).but still no luck ;-(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you failed to include jQuery, jQuery UI, and you're using an outdated version of jquery.event.drag. You can get the updated version here: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag

Comment: @ibehold - the version of jquery.event.drag has been updated together with the reference.may I know how to include jQuery & jQuery UI corretctly?

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code in my IDE and behold, A brace and a parenthesis was missing in at the end of our slickGridTest.js code..